# Displaying ggvis in Powerpoint

Tags: r, server, powerpoint, shiny, ggvis

Has anyone been able to come up with a way to display `ggvis` (or `htmlwidgets` etc.) interactive plots in a powerpoint presentation? These usually require a web server, but is there anyway to open a localhost and run in powerpoint?

If not, how have you gone about presenting interactive R graphs in presentations?

Comment: Why Powerpoint? [Presentation support](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html) in RStudio is great.

Comment: This is very cool, thank you for pointing me to ioslides.  This might just be the answer. `ggvis` plays with `knitr` and `rmarkdown` really nicely as well.